# Where can I see my device's BLE UUID?

Tags: bluetooth, ios

I've been working on a project in which I need to pair an iPhone with my RPi. I've successfully done it, only that I would like to know how can I get the RPi's BLE UUID my iPhone sees when it scans for nearby peripherals from the RPi itself.

Is there any command or tool that can help me with this?

Comment: For command line on a linux based distribution, `hcitool info` should work. However, depending on what you are doing you may need to setup bluetooth first on the Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found out that the UUID I get from my iPhone scanning results is calculated BY THE IOS ITSELF FROM THE MAC ADDRESS and the RPi doesn't aware of it...